# How to find the real size of a file partially downloaded from a Torrent client, using the terminal?

Tags: command-line

A certain program I'm developing, requires to be fed with some file sizes on the disk, in order to work.. I'm using the stat command in Terminal to achieve this.. However, stat can't calculate the actual size of the files downloded from a Bittorrent client. Does anyone know a way to do it? THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean how much disk space is used holding the parts already downloaded, that would be the Blocks x Block Size that `stat` reports.

Comment: Got it... stat -c '%b × %B' filename